# Can't get any values in the cursor

Tags: android, sqlite, android-cursor

I'm confused why I can't get any values in the `cursor`.
What's wrong in my code..

here's the code..

```
 sqLiteDatabase = getReadableDatabase();
 Cursor cursor = sqLiteDatabase.query("bank",new String[]{"name", "acno", "available"},"bank_index = ?",new String[]{String.valueOf(bank_index)},null,null,null);
 cursor.moveToFirst();
 String name = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("name"));
 String acno = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("acno"));
 contentValues.put("bank", name + " Account number: " + acno);
```

I got error of `CursorOutOfBoundsException` on last third line of the above code..

query of the table:

```
 sqLiteDatabase.execSQL("create table bank(bank_index integer primary key,name text,acno text,branch text,available text)");
```

Comment: no... but what's the difference.. Why I always get empty cursor..

Comment: Just copy your database file in external storage and check it by "https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=dk.andsen.asqlitemanager&hl=en" app. which will show all your tables and let you run queries also.

Answer (score 1):

Before performing any operation on cursor, you must check

```
if(cursor != null && cursor.getCount() > 0 ) {
   //go ahead
}

//You can also try
String query = "SELECT name, acno, available FROM bank WHERE bank_index = '"+String.valueOf(bank_index)+"'";
Cursor cursor = sqLiteDatabase.rawQuery(query,null);
```

Comment: I know but why my cursor is empty??

Comment: You may not have entries in your table.

Comment: i have to learn how to use it first brother... But I'm damn sure that the table has the values...

Comment: @pskink no need to go to the table... I know there are data in it as i can retrieve the data without using the where Clause... But can't get any data by using where bank_index = bla bla bla

Comment: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such table: bank (code 1): , while compiling: select * from bank

Comment: yes... it does.. but your code needs some modifications in order to get compiled without errors

Comment: the thing i'm trying to say is when i retrieve data from the table "bank" without using the where clause... the data is retrieved successfully... but when i'm using it with where clause... i get no data...

Comment: Your table may not have data as per the where clause you're supplying. Did you tried the other way to query the data? I had made edit to answer. Check it out.

Comment: @dpaksoni yes... I tried every possible way to execute the sql... But in vain

Comment: @pskink there was no log

Comment: @pskink no... I put this code in the onCreate method of a class (in my app.. it's DBhelper) which extends SqLiteOpenHelper

Comment: @pskink for seeing the logs... We use logcat.. right?

Comment: But when i try to get the data
.. it shows that there is no such table